# Jboss 7 log issues

Tags: logging, jboss, jboss7.x

I've installed Jboss 7.1.1.Final as a window service according to [this guide](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/RunningJBossAS7AsAWindowsService).

Everything is working fine, except for the logs. It seems like everything is being logged twice! Firstly in a file named `server.log` and then in a file named `standalone.log`.

The `server.log` file is neatly renamed everyday, so I got 1 small log file for any given day (server.log.2014-06-12, server.log.2014-06-13, and so on...), each file having no more than 20MB.

The `standalone.log` on the other hand keeps getting bigger and bigger, so when it reaches something like 3GB the app crashes and I have to manually restart it.

How can I prevent Jboss from logging to this `standalone.log`?

I have found some references to this file in the `service.bat` I've used to register the Windows service, so I'm posting the complete contents of this file bellow:

```
@echo off
REM JBoss, the OpenSource webOS
REM
REM Distributable under LGPL license.
REM See terms of license at gnu.org.
REM
REM -------------------------------------------------------------------------
REM JBoss Service Script for Windows
REM -------------------------------------------------------------------------


@if not "%ECHO%" == "" echo %ECHO%
@if "%OS%" == "Windows_NT" setlocal
set DIRNAME=%CD%

REM
REM VERSION, VERSION_MAJOR and VERSION_MINOR are populated
REM during the build with ant filter.
REM
set SVCNAME=JBAS50SVC
set SVCDISP=JBoss 7
set SVCDESC=JBoss 7.1.1
set NOPAUSE=Y

REM Suppress killing service on logoff event
REM set JAVA_OPTS=-Xrs

REM Figure out the running mode

if /I "%1" == "install"   goto cmdInstall
if /I "%1" == "uninstall" goto cmdUninstall
if /I "%1" == "start"     goto cmdStart
if /I "%1" == "stop"      goto cmdStop
if /I "%1" == "restart"   goto cmdRestart
if /I "%1" == "signal"    goto cmdSignal
echo Usage: service install^|uninstall^|start^|stop^|restart^|signal
goto cmdEnd

REM jbosssvc retun values
REM ERR_RET_USAGE           1
REM ERR_RET_VERSION         2
REM ERR_RET_INSTALL         3
REM ERR_RET_REMOVE          4
REM ERR_RET_PARAMS          5
REM ERR_RET_MODE            6

:errExplain
if errorlevel 1 echo Invalid command line parameters
if errorlevel 2 echo Failed installing %SVCDISP%
if errorlevel 4 echo Failed removing %SVCDISP%
if errorlevel 6 echo Unknown service mode for %SVCDISP%
goto cmdEnd

:cmdInstall
jbosssvc.exe -imwdc %SVCNAME% "%DIRNAME%" "%SVCDISP%" "%SVCDESC%" service.bat
if not errorlevel 0 goto errExplain
echo Service %SVCDISP% installed
goto cmdEnd

:cmdUninstall
jbosssvc.exe -u %SVCNAME%
if not errorlevel 0 goto errExplain
echo Service %SVCDISP% removed
goto cmdEnd

:cmdStart
REM Executed on service start
del .r.lock 2>&1 | findstr /C:"being used" > nul
if not errorlevel 1 (
  echo Could not continue. Locking file already in use.
  goto cmdEnd
)
echo Y > .r.lock
jbosssvc.exe -p 1 "Starting %SVCDISP%" > C:\Web\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\log\standalone.log
call standalone.bat --server-config=standalone.xml < .r.lock >> C:\Web\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\log\standalone.log 2>&1
jbosssvc.exe -p 1 "Shutdown %SVCDISP% service" >> C:\Web\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\log\standalone.log
del .r.lock
goto cmdEnd

:cmdStop
REM Executed on service stop
echo Y > .s.lock
jbosssvc.exe -p 1 "Shutting down %SVCDISP%" > C:\Web\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\log\shutdown.log
call jboss-cli.bat --connect command=:shutdown >> C:\Web\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\log\shutdown.log 2>&1
jbosssvc.exe -p 1 "Shutdown %SVCDISP% service" >> C:\Web\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\log\shutdown.log
del .s.lock
goto cmdEnd

:cmdRestart
REM Executed manually from command line
REM Note: We can only stop and start
echo Y > .s.lock
jbosssvc.exe -p 1 "Shutting down %SVCDISP%" >> C:\Web\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\log\shutdown.log
call jboss-cli.bat --connect command=:shutdown >> C:\Web\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\log\shutdown.log 2>&1
del .s.lock
:waitRun
REM Delete lock file
del .r.lock > nul 2>&1
REM Wait one second if lock file exist
jbosssvc.exe -s 1
if exist ".r.lock" goto waitRun
echo Y > .r.lock
jbosssvc.exe -p 1 "Restarting %SVCDISP%" >> C:\Web\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\log\standalone.log
call standalone.bat --server-config=standalone.xml < .r.lock >> C:\Web\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\log\standalone.log 2>&1
jbosssvc.exe -p 1 "Shutdown %SVCDISP% service" >> C:\Web\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\log\standalone.log
del .r.lock
goto cmdEnd

:cmdSignal
REM Send signal to the service.
REM Requires jbosssch.dll to be loaded in JVM
@if not ""%2"" == """" goto execSignal
echo Missing signal parameter.
echo Usage: service signal [0...9]
goto cmdEnd
:execSignal
jbosssvc.exe -k%2 %SVCNAME%
goto cmdEnd

:cmdEnd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve what I wanted by editing the **standalone.xml** configuration file.

This part:

```
    <root-logger>
        <level name="INFO"/>
        <handlers>
            <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
            <handler name="FILE"/>
        </handlers>
    </root-logger>
```

Was changed to this:

```
    <root-logger>
        <level name="INFO"/>
        <handlers>
            <handler name="FILE"/>
        </handlers>
    </root-logger>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the script (standalone.bat) you'll see the stdout is being redirected to the `standalone.log` file. You can disable the console handler which should prevent anything from being logged to the file.

Remove the default `console-handler` from the root logger:

```
/subsystem=logging/root-logger=ROOT:root-logger-unassign-handler(name=CONSOLE)
```

Comment: Thanks James. Sorry for my inexperience, but on which file should I look for that root logger?

Comment: They're the same. If you do a `/subsystem=logging/root-logger=ROOT:read-resource` you'll see both a CONSOLE and FILE handler have been assigned. Essentially your CONSOLE is just being redirected to a file.